# Sections in UITableView with UITableViewStyleGrouped "taking" background with them on scroll

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have this code to set the background image of the UITableViewController:

```
self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg5.jpg"]];
```

Thats in `viewDidLoad`.

On scrolling the table the part of that background image around each section goes with it, annoyingly. If I add a title and header to these sections then the background goes with that too. :/

Any ideas what is causing this?

**EDIT**
it doesn't seem to be taking the background with it to be honest, its as if each section has its own version of the background - which is even more annoying, because even when stationary the background looks out of place.

Thanks

Tom

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
self.navigationController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Background.png"]];
self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

does it. :)

Answer (score 0):

if you are using a UITableViewCell. In Interface Builder try to set all of the outlets
**background** to clear color. **but I mean every thing**. if you have labels, backgroundImages, even the view everything goes with clear color.

Comment: its ok - I found it (i don't use interface builder) will answer below

Comment: I hear you, code works better. tried it and Im loving how it works.